# Allow php script to write file for all users

Tags: php, permissions

I wrote a very simple php script, to list, create and delete files and directories.

Now I want this script to create and delete files and folders for all users. How can I do this task ?

For test, I stored this script to /var/www/test-fm/index.php and create the alias named /filemanager and set the initial directory for /home/. It's listing all the files for all the users. But when tried to create a new file or folder it's giving me the warning **that I am not allowed to write**. I know generally we couldn't write files for different users. However, I thought there would BE some solutions.

Is there any way to allow this php script to write files for all users ? Server is running the Ubuntu 14.04 and I have ssh access over server.

Comment: One way of solving this would be to put all the users into a certain group (ubuntu group) and then give that group read/write permission to that folder, although you'd also most likely need to give the web-user / user that executes the script read / write access to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will start from the parent directory which contain all of the sub-directories, read all of the sub directories no need to go at child level, which you read first sub-directory than unlink() that directory, it should automatically delete all of the child directories. one by one it will delete all of the main sub-directory, you have use some recursive way for this.

Comment: make sure directories should have 777 permissions

Comment: if the directories have 777 permissions, isn't this assumed to be risk ?